# Warning message at R startup (slidify, rmarkdown)

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, slidify

When I startup my R (in RStudio IDE), I receive the warning:

> Warning: namespace ‘slidify’ is not available and has been replaced by
>   .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘.SLIDIFY_ENV’

Yesterday I uninstalled `slidify` (and `slidifyLibraries`) as this package interfered with regular use or `.Rmd` (Rmarkdown) files (when I pushet `knit` button in RStudio, all the .Rmd files were rendered as `slidify` slides, despite the fact that they had to be rendered as usual Rmarkdown files).

**Question:** How can I get rid of the warning message at the startup?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Warning: namespace ‘slidify’ is not available and has been replaced by
>   .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘.SLIDIFY_ENV’

That is telling you there's an object called `.SLIDIFY_ENV` in your R workspace at startup which is associated with the now-missing `slidify` namespace. Remove it (`rm(.SLIDIFY_ENV)` should work), save your workspace. Restart R and it shouldn't re-occur.

Comment: I tried `ls(all.names = TRUE)`  and discovered, that environment `.SLIDIFY_ENV` exists in the workspace. `rm(.SLIDIFY_ENV)` worked. Thank you @Spacedman

Answer (score 6):

You probably had .RData in your workspace, which contains those variables.

If you remove .RData file, then you will not be going to see the warning message.