RStudio packages no longer installed
This morning when I opened up my RStudio, I had the following warning in my console window:
Warning: namespace ‘ggplot2’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘p1’
In addition, RStudio had notices on all of my scripts about missing packages. I went ahead and told it to reinstall the packages, but some of the installs failed (tidyverse).
Everything was working fine 2 days ago. Does anyone know why this may be happening? Do I possibly need to upgrade my R Studio? I am running RStudio 2022.02.1 Build 4

Some comments and suggestions for the same error from these prior questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77153176/6851825 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302681/namespace-not-available-and-replaced-with-globalenv and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906819/warning-message-at-r-startup-slidify-rmarkdown and https://forum.posit.co/t/since-newest-rstudio-update-ggplot-the-downloaded-source-packages-are-in-private-var-downloaded-packages/19034.
